# Getting a cable below the foundation slab

Tags: wiring, foundation, waterproofing, ethernet

I don't think I will be able to explain this well so I hope an image will do some heavy lifting. My problem is, I cannot go get a cable directly into the basement via attic->outside wall. The only option seems to be through the basement wall. I have noticed that the cinder block will weep a bit on wet days so it is likely the water table is a factor. Do I just insulate the hole? I know cement is porous so I worry a hard patch will introduce more moisture in the cracks formed by drilling. Is there a better way to approach this? (I only put 3 cinder blocks but its a full size room)
[image: complicated cables]

Comment: Can you use the same path a person would use to go down into the basement?

Comment: A) What kind of cable? (power, coax, Ethernet, steel?) B) Are there any open conduits from the attic down to the basement that run through the slab? You may be able to use one of them so long as you don't over fill it. C) Are there any interior walls that you could use instead of this exterior wall? It might take more cable, but would avoid a below ground wall penetration. D) Do you really have a poured concrete slab above your basement?

Comment: Where does the cable come from outside? Please show that, as it'll give better ideas, maybe.

Comment: On the worst cases I usually will cut a hole mid wall in the first floor and use a long bit with a tennis ball to center the bit in the wall and punch a hole up then down and use a “fish rod” or “glow stick” to fish the cable through the wall. A small patch and the path is there. I plug the holes after running cables with fire stop putty or calking.

Comment: @aparente001 the stairs are also cinderblock and very narrow so it may be hard but I may consider that.

Comment: @FreeMan A) CAT6 Ethernet B) Not that I can see, I think this addition was custom so its not very "up to code" C) No interior walls unfortunately D) it might be cinder blocks not a slab but I did not want to drill into it unless it was my only option

Comment: @Tim it comes down from the the outside under the roof

Comment: @EdBeal That might be worth a shot.